# Java hash code is working differently on different machines

Tags: java, spring, lombok

I am having **hash code** generated by lombok and using that as an identifier. Logic is as below:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public final class TestIdentifier {

   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private final LocalDate dob;

}
```

This is how I create an object:

```
TestIdentifier testIdentifier = new TestIdentifier(
          StringUtils.lowerCase(value.getFirstName()),
          StringUtils.lowerCase(value.getLastName()),
          LocalDate.ofEpochDay(
              value.getDateOfBirth()));
```

```
testIdentifier.hashCode()
```

**Use Case:**
Consider two persons with following first name/ last name and DOB. I am expecting hash to be same for both of them.

Person1:

FIRSTNAME LASTNAME 2000-08-09

Person2:

firstname lastname 2000-08-09

Issue:

The hash code for the persons is coming the same in my Local but when I promoting this code to a different environment they are leading to different hash codes.

I am not able to figure out the issue. So looking for help!!

Comment: My suspicion is that it's a timezone issue. Log the actual values at runtime (you probably want to add `@ToString`).

Comment: It's not timezone. I checked that.

Comment: 'Using that as an identifier': you can't do that. Hash codes are not unique by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very old versions of lombok used slightly different prime numbers in the hashcode algorithm; this was changed, knowing it could break some existing code, for the very reason said in the answer by @Pruthvik: You're not supposed to rely on consistent hashcodes between different VM invokes.

However, it sounds like you're getting different hashcodes for the *same* VM invoke, with presumably equal fields - this cannot be due to lombok being involved.

It must mean your fields are not actually equal. At least, lombok generates the hashcode by generating one for each field; the way lombok generates the 'sub' hashcode for all your 3 listed fields is all the same: By simply calling the `hashCode()` method on those objects. So, those are probably changing.

To debug this, write a method that prints out the hashcode returned by each field individually. Find the place where they differ, and you'll find different objects. For example, if your current locale is turkish, capital I is lowercased to a dotless i, thus, `"Jim".toLowerCase()` is not equal to `"JIM".toLowerCase()` on all VMs. That sounds like a plausible explanation.

I have no idea why in the blazes you'd farm out the job to an apache library of all things, but I did a quick check for the docs and this stringutils method truly is as useless as it sounds. It just calls `toLowerCase()`. Which does have this 'well, according to current locale' issue going on. Try `lowerCase(theInput, Locale.ENGLISH)`, perhaps.

NB: The theory that you can lowercase a string to normalize comparisons is a misconception. It works in english, but it doesn't for many other languages. Unless you want to tack a rule 'this software does not work unless all its users speak english, dutch, german, danish, and a few other western languages', you may want to reduce your reliance on lowercasing things and then using that for identity. And that dutch thing might not even work out, they have that weird dotted Y thing going on. ("YPENBURG".toLowerCase() probably should be "ijpenburg" in proper dutch, though unlike with turkish I don't think the locale setting would actually do that).

Comment: does uppercase has a better chance for identity than lowercase?

Comment: @JDev no; in turkish, "jim".toUpperCase() becomes "JİM". That's a dotted, capital I, and not the same as the dotless I (the one you get when you hit SHIFT+i on a standard keyboard). "ijpenburg", the dutch place, in capitals, is "YPENBURG".

Answer (score -1):

I believe for your use case of comparing two TestIdentifier objects, using the equals() method to compare all the data members is a better option. 
The reason being, hashcode() contract states that calling this method() on an object returns the same integer value when the object is not modified and is mainly used with hashtables.

The java contract clearly states that "This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application. "

Reference Java doc if you need to read more : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()

Comment: My requirement is to generate the hash and put it in DB. I am not comparing the objects.

Comment: "The value returned by hashCode() is the object's hash code, which is the object's memory address in hexadecimal."  from [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) , so I don't think you will be able to get the same value on different machines.

Comment: I was not expecting that but I was expecting that on the same machine the hash would be generated consistently

Comment: As mentioned already, it is based on the object itself rather than the data member values. So even on the same machine, it is not expected to return the either same/different integer consistently. Because two different objects with the same data member values may still not be the same hexadecimal representation of the memory address. The contract only promises that calling hashcode() on an object which does not change will return the same value, does not apply to other objects with same values even if on the same machine. 

Hope that cleared it up ! :)

Comment: You are answering the wrong question. He is asking why two objects with equal hashcodes in one machine have unequal hashcodes in another. And as he is using generated `hashCode()` methods, it certainly has nothing to do with hex or the object address.